# Account for variable to add more variation to predictor variable scipy

Tags: logistic, python, scipy, pandas

Is there a test or method to account for the interaction between predictor variables to influence the outcome in a regression model. Specifically, if a variable increases in value, it may add more variation to the outcome and lessen the influence of the other predictor variable.

To provide an example below, let's say `A` ranges from 0-5. As it increases in value, the likelihood of an event occurring increases. However, this is more accurate if `B` is lower in value. For instance, if `B` ranges from 0-10, it lessens the impact of `A` or adds more variation to the outcome if the value is closer to 10 but `A` holds more weight when `B` is closer to 1.

Is there a way to test for this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 6, size = (100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
df['B'] = np.random.randint(0, 11, df.shape[0])
df['Outcome'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, df.shape[0])

X = df[['A','B']]
y = df['Outcome']

log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(X, y)

prob = log_reg.predict_proba(X)[:,1]

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 42)

formula = ('Outcome ~ A + B')

model = logit(formula = formula, data = train_data).fit()

params = model.params
conf = model.conf_int()
conf['Odds Ratio'] = params
conf['z-value'] = model.pvalues
conf.columns = ['5%', '95%', 'Odds Ratio','z-value']

print(model.summary())
print('\nOdds Ratio Table: \n' + str (np.exp(conf)) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interaction terms in statistics are considered in a variety of cases, and the hypothetical situation you mention can be clearly translated as the interaction, $A*B$. There are a number of ways you could test whether this interaction term is important to include in your model. Assuming linearity, you could fit a regression model including the $A*B$ interaction, and simply assess the coefficient value, standard error, and p-value associated with the interaction term.

A more complete method would perhaps be to fit one model with the interaction term (*full* model), and one without the interaction term (*reduced* model). Then, you may compare the two models with a likelihood ratio test (LRT). Letting $l(m)$ represent the log-likelihood of a model, the LRT statistic is:

$$-2[l(m_{reduced}) - l(m_{full})]$$

Which, under the null hypothesis, is distributed according to a $\chi^2$ distribution with degrees of freedom (df) equivalent to the difference in dimensionality of the models. The df in your case will likely be $1$ if you are just testing for the importance of the one interaction term. This leads to a clear interpretation of whether the full model (which includes the interaction) makes a significant improvement over the reduced model. You can learn more details about the LRT to compare two nested models [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/lesson/6/6.2/6.2.3), and find a clear guide to implementation [here](https://api.rpubs.com/tomanderson_34/lrt).

In Jérémy's answer, he also mentioned some resources for nonlinear modeling. I wouldn't necessarily recommend jumping straight to that if you haven't assessed linear associations yet (due to the simplicity of interpretation of linear models, if anything), but if you deem it appropriate to try nonlinear methods, those are some good resources and recommendations to explore.

Comment: @chopin if this answer was helpful to you, or the other answer was, you may mark them as the accepted answer for the bounty to get awarded. Happy to also answer any follow-up queries you may have on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common practice to add interaction between two variables in a regression model by adding a new covariate beeing the product of them. However, in your question, you seem to be interested by potential non-linear interaction. To stay in the regression framework, you could use a GAM (generalized additive model), which uses splines to model non-linear relations between you predictors and your outcome. It is also possible to specify two dimensionnal splines to model the impact of their non linear interaction. I never tried it in python, but the reference package in R is [MGCV](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html). The library [pyGAM](https://pygam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/tour_of_pygam.html) might be what you need in python.
I hope it will help.